# Determining a rule which assigns each ring a unit element

Tags: commutative-algebra

Probably this is easiest, but as I am somehow stuck I would be pleased about some comments.

What I give myself is a rule $f$ which does the following:

To every commutative ring $A$ with $1$ the rule $f$ assigns a unit $f(A)\in A^*$, and this assignment shall satisfy the following property:

If $\varphi: A\rightarrow B$ is any ring homomorphism, then $\varphi(f(A)) =f(B)$.

I am convinced that the only rules which can do this are the following two:

(i) $f(A)=1$ for each ring $A$ simultaneously,

(ii) $f(A)=-1$ for each ring $A$ simultaneously.

How could one show this (if it is right)?

Comment: Should the rule say "$f(A) \in A^*$" or "$f(A) \in A$?" I am confused as $\phi$ is not a homomorphism with domain $A^*$.

Comment: One could generalize and ask the analogous question for $R$-algebras instead or rings. Manny's nice proof carries over to this setting and shows that the set of those rules is in canonical bijection to the set of units in $R$. By the way, such a rule is the same as a natural transformation from $K_{\{\star\}}$ to $(-)^\times$, where $K_{\{\star\}}$ is the functor which associates to any ring the set $\{\star\}$ and $(-)^\times$ is the functor which associates to any ring its set of units.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the context of the problem, I am assuming that you want to impose the following conditions:

- "Commutative ring" means commutative ring with identity.
- "Ring homomorphism" means a homomorphism that preserves identity elements.

In this case, your guess is correct.  Here is a proof.

First, consider that $f(\mathbb{Z}) \in \mathbb{Z}^* = \{1,-1\}$.

Next, let $A$ be any commutative ring.  Then there is a unique homomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{Z} \to A$, determined by $\phi(1) = 1$.  Given your requirements for the assignment $f$, it follows that $$f(A) = \phi(f(\mathbb{Z})).$$  If $f(\mathbb{Z}) = 1$, we conclude from the equation above that $f(A) = 1$ also. If $f(\mathbb{Z}) = -1$, it follows similarly that $f(A) = -1$.  Thus $f$ falls into either case (i) or case (ii), to use your notation.

(How did I produce this answer?  I looked for a *universal* example where I could use concrete reasoning.  The commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is "universal" in the sense that it has a unique homomorphism to every ring.  The problem became much easier after understanding this specific example!)

Answer (score 1):

One program that often works for these sorts of questions is:

- Select one or more rings for which it is easy to solve for all possibilities
- Study if and how these solutions extend to all rings.